# How to prepare a Centos ISO for creation of Xen domU guest with xl (not xm or virt-install)

Tags: linux, centos-6, xen

I'm tearing my hair out.

I will be scripting the creation of large numbers of small HVM (not PV) customer xen CentOS 6.5 guests on a CentOS 6.5 dom0. I therefore do not want to use virt-manager (I'm scripting). I also do not want to use xm as it's deprecated - and most of the docs on the web talk about using it.

I want to use only the xl toolstack to create and manage my VMs.
I've read the documentation for xl and the spin-off docs about specifying disk info in the cfg file. They don't give me practical advice as to how to take a CentOS6.5 minimal ISO and preparing it for use as a xen image and I cannot find a suitable guide anywhere else. I have the resources to set up a pxe-based install, but I'd rather keep the image local to the dom0 as it will be faster than transferring the data over the network.

Surely someone here can at least point me in the right direction of such instructions! I can't believe it's this hard to find decent up-to-date documentation.